# flex i am confused

Tags: c, flex-lexer

input to lexer

```
abc gef4 44jdjd ghghg
x
ererete
xyzzz
55k
hello wold
33
```

my rules

```
rule1 [0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+
rule2 [x-z]
rule3 .*
```

{rule1} {
printf("%s \n", yytext);
}

{rule2} {
printf("%s \n", yytext);
}

{rule3} {
// prints nothing
}

output :-

```
x  



55k
```

I cannot understand the output ? Can someone please help me.

Comment: a lot of strings are being matched with rule3 why is that ? why did rule3 match word 44jdjd ? It should have being matched with rule1 since rule1 appears first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first character of the input neither matches rule1 nor rule2. Instead rule3 eats input up to the end of line. The same happens on line 3, 4, 6, and 7. You probably want a less greedy rule3, i.e. one that doesn't consume the spaces:

```
[^ \t\n]*           /* Do nothing */
```

Then 44jdjd is being found by rule1.

Comment: it now prints unwanted words as well. I guess i have to write a regex to eat those. How can i put two regular expressions on a single rule ? this doesnt work rule3 [^ \t\n] | [a-z-Z]*